# How to interpret this particular SMTP response by AOL?

Tags: smtp

Connect to AOL's mail server:

```
telnet mailin-01.mx.aol.com 25
```

You receive:

```
554- (RTR:DU)  https://postmaster.aol.com/error-codes#554rtrdu
554  Connecting IP: 82.xxx.xxx.xxx

Connection to host lost.
```

Interestingly, the line breaks after the first two lines are `<CR><CR><LF>`. This is not visible in the telnet output. I determined this using a C# program that prints the bytes.

This appears to be invalid SMTP behavior. Is it? How to deal with that when writing an SMTP client?

(I understand the reason for the error code. The question is not about that but about the apparent protocol violation.)

Comment: I can hardly see how that would be significant. Everything after the RTR code is commentary anyway.

Comment: It matters because I must develop my parser so that it correctly understands SMTP responses. It's obvious to a human that this is "commentary" but not to a machine.

Comment: My advice would be to take everything before the CRLF as data, including any number of isolated CR or LF characters. Maybe fall back to a different line terminator discipline if you see a lot of one and none of the other.

Comment: @tripleee that might work. I might try that. Do you think I also could just ignore empty lines? .NET cannot be customized to ignore <CR>-only line endings. I'd have to do a lot myself.

Comment: Empty lines within a sequence are problematic - the 554- needs to be followed by a 554 without a dash, everything else would be a protocol error. But with Postel's law in mind, perhaps that could work. Do you actually see remote servers producing empty lines?

Comment: So far I tested only about 10 servers and did not see any such thing. Only the strange AOL thing which actually might be valid.